# Can you derive the exponential property $ [f(x+y) = f(x)\cdot f(y)]$ from $y' = y$?

Tags: calculus

There are a variety of different ways to define the natural exponential function, but the definition that feels the most conceptually elegant to me is to define it as *the* function that is its own derivative, and that $\text{exp}(0)=1$. I am currently trying to figure out if it is possible to derive all the properties of $e^x$/$\text{exp}(x)$ merely from this fact. In addition, I have defined the natural logarithm to simply be the inverse of $\text{exp}(x)$, which was enough to determine that the derivative of $\ln{x}$ is $\frac{1}{x}$. I have been trying in vain to prove from this definition that $\forall{k}\in\mathbb{R},\text{exp}(x+k)=\text{exp}(x)\space\cdot\space\text{exp}(k)$.

Comment: FYI, there's more than just $y = e^x$ and $0$, there's any function of the form $y = Ae^x$ for some constant $A$. If you want to uniquely define the exponential function from a differential equation, it's customary to include the initial value condition $y(0) = 1$.

Comment: @user837206 Ahh, thank you for the correction. I did forget to include the initial condition. I will edit the post to include that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that (provided $\exp(k)\ne0$), we have for $f(x):=\frac{\exp(x+k)}{\exp(k)}$,
$$f(0)=\frac{\exp(0+k)}{\exp(k)}=1,\qquad f'(x)=\frac{\exp'(x+k)}{\exp(k)}=\frac{\exp(x+k)}{\exp(k)}=f(x)$$
so that by uniqueness of the solution,  $f(x)=\exp(x)$ for all $x$.
Hence,
$$ \exp(x+k)=\exp(x)\exp(k)\quad \text{if }\exp(k)\ne0.$$
As $\exp(0)=1$, we have $\exp(k)\ne0$ in a neighbourhood of $0$, hence if $\exp(x)=0$, then $\exp$ is also $=0$ in a neighbourhood of $x$. It follows that
$$\{\,x\in\Bbb R\mid \exp(x)=0\,\} $$
is open - but it trivially is also closed, and is non-empty. This means that it is all of $\Bbb R$. Hence we can strike our caveats and have
$$ \exp(x+k)=\exp(x)\exp(k)\quad \text{for all }x,k\in \Bbb R.$$

Comment: Wait, shouldn't $\{x\in\mathbb R\mid\exp(x)=0\}$ be _empty_?

Answer (score 0):

Both expressions solve the initial value problem
$$y'(x)=y(x)
,\quad
y(0)=\exp(k),$$
which has a unique solution. So they must be equal.

(More conceptually, that identity is a reflection of the fact that solutions of first-order ODEs are **flows**.)